# how to display materialize icons?

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea, materialize

I have simple html page and use materialize CSS framework. I want to use materialize icons. `<head>` tag contains

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="../css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

`<body>` contains:

```
<div class="search-wrapper card">
   <input id="search">
   <i class="material-icons">search</i>
   <div class="search-results"></div>
</div>
```

Page displays it as text, not icon

if i put `<i class="small mdi-action-search"></i>` then it works.

But i don't understand why `<i class="material-icons">search</i>` doesn't work.

What should i do to make it works?

Comment: Probably because the materialize framework is included after the `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` and its overwrite the styles set for the i elements by the material icons css.

Comment: Or an older browser that's not compatible with the ligature..

Comment: According to me it is the matter of position of defining the links / scripts. You should consider changing the position of <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> before framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I use IntelliJ Idea, `utf-16` encoding was used by default for some reason.

Right clicking on the file content and changing file encoding to `utf-8` helped

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in head u need add these to project if u dont have

```
  <link href="css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

in body add this script

```
<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

examaple usage

```
<i class="material-icons left">search</i>
```

this is head part of one of my project's code

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <!-- Your app title -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <!-- Color theme for statusbar -->

    <title>My App</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <!--<link href="lib/framework7.ios.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="lib/framework7.ios.colors.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <link href="lib/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="lib/framework7.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="lib/framework7.material.colors.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="lib/my-app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: it's not the way to achieve this #cagri. Script whether in <head> or <body> doesn't matter. It works always. According to me it is the matter of position of defining the links / scripts.